# I want to change text color using class and onclick function but onclick function not working?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'


class Changecolor extends Component{
    changeme=()=>{<p className='redme'>You Got Me Now Im Red as Tomato Thank you</p>;}
    render(){
        return(
            <div className='testclass'>
                <h1>Click me to change my Color</h1>
                <p>Hi Please change my color to red Click below button</p>
                <button onClick={this.changeme}>Click Me to change Color</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Changecolor;
```

Comment: This might be helpful If you're looking for [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-react-class-mqnndj)

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = { 
    clicked:false
  }
}

changeme = () =>{
  this.setState({clicked:true})

}


const clickedText = "You Got Me Now Im Red as Tomato Thank you",
const clickedClassName = "redme"


    render(){
        return(
            <div className='testclass'>
                <h1>Click me to change my Color</h1>
                {clicked ? <p className={clickedClassName}>{clickedText}</p> : <p>Hi Please change my color to red Click below button</p>}
                
                <button onClick={this.changeme}>Click Me to change Color</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the JSX inside `changeme` click handler, you should write code like this:
`changeme=()=> <p className='redme'>You Got Me Now Im Red as Tomato Thank you</p>` (without curly braces)

For changing color of anything when clicking a button, the idea here is storing a flag in state and adding style base on the value of that flag.

For example, I want to change text of this `<p>` tag to red when click on the button.

`<p>Hi Please change my color to red Click below button</p>`

The code should look like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'


class Changecolor extends Component{
    state = { coloring: false };
    changeme=()=>{
      this.setState({coloring: true})
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className='testclass'>
                <h1>Click me to change my Color</h1>
                <p style={this.state.coloring && { color: 'red'}}>Hi Please change my color to red Click below button</p>
                <button onClick={this.changeme}>Click Me to change Color</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Changecolor;
```